# Setting Xcode 15 default AccentColor

Tags: swiftui, xcode15

I'm following the instructions for setting a custom color on `AccentColor` in xcassets catalog:
[image]

Made sure the build setting was in place:
[image]

But none of the buttons in my app are affected by this color.

Instead I need to add this to see it in simulator:

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .accentColor(.accent)
}
```

and I need to set this on every preview to see it in the preview system.

Example of button code I'm using, but I've tried every buttonStyle of button/navigationLink, none of them get the AccentColor tint color automatically, I still have to set this manually on every button:

```
Button {
    
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "plus")
        .font(.system(size: 40))
}
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
.clipShape(Capsule())
```

I assumed the whole point of this asset was so I wouldn't need to do this? Is this a known issue or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: No you don't need to do the second part, just the first one should be enough.
Putting in a json color file for your ```AccentColor```. and then you'll have to set for each button wherever you want to.

Comment: You can't use ```.accentColor(.accent)``` and expect it to change the color of every button in your views.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of a button that is not affected by the color.

Comment: if its a macOS app you also have to enable custom accent colours in preferences > appearance > accent color

Comment: @Sweeper Added some button code for you, it's pretty typical. Based on the other responses, I actually need to set my new global AccentColor on every button? That's crazy...

Comment: Still cannot reproduce on iOS. If it is for macOS then you should do as ChrisR said.

Comment: You're correct @Sweeper I created a brand new empty project, added a button, set the color in assets to red and it reflected fine. I must have something messing up my project. I'm going to research this a bit more and post the cause once I track it down, just in case anyone else runs into this...

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper was able to track this down to something really insane causing it. See posted answer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Sweeper for his comments helping me with this.

I was able to track down what was causing this by creating a new project (which showed the global accent color fine) and slowly applying my current project's code to it.

The cause is something really crazy... seems to have to do with setting a Data value on a SwiftData property during initialization.

Here's the most basic example:

**Code for @main app:**

```
@main
struct test_accent_colorApp: App {
    var appManager = AppManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(appManager.testDataModelContainer)
    }
}
```

Basically creating an AppManager class which creates some dummy SwiftData preview content.

**App Manager class:**

```
@Observable class AppManager {
    var testDataModelContainer: ModelContainer = previewContainer
}
```

All this does is initialize a test data container.

**Preview container code:**

```
@MainActor
let previewContainer: ModelContainer = {
    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(
            for: Item.self,
            configurations: ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
        )
        let item = Item(timestamp: Date())
        container.mainContext.insert(item)
        return container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to create container \(error)")
    }
}()
```

This is a global variable, just creates a single Item entry with the current date, nothing else.

**Item Model:**

```
@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    var image: Data?
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        
        //Global tint works
        self.image = nil
        
        //Global tint doesn't work
//        self.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!
    }
}
```

Here, it has just 2 properties. The Data? property is what causes Gobal Tint to break down.

Here is when I initialize the item.image to nil, global tint works:
[image]

Here is when I initialize the item.image with an image from the app bundle:
[image]

Link to [sample project zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5ms3ddk8bhc7bmc6xw4f8/test-accent-color.zip?rlkey=fg58steundocqwcgufm2yqdcu&dl=0) if anyone is curious.

Comment: I cannot facepalm hard enough. Thanks for getting to the bottom of this, you saved me a bunch a time. Did you find a workaround for tinting your whole app anyway?

Comment: Ok, using `.accentColor(.accent)` on the root View looks like it works (but won't propagate to modal views as described in https://adampaxton.com/how-to-globally-set-a-tint-or-accent-color-in-swiftui/). Good enough for me...

Comment: Thank you so much, I never would have traced this down. I only encountered this issue when running UI Testing / fastlane snapshot because I seed my model container with mock objects in my UI Test scheme. What I did to solve in general was to move my data generation into a task on my main app container instead of doing it in my app launch init.